# How does a NPM package get its own install directory path?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to make a NPM package with a native executable file that is used by the package.

The package needs to know the path of the file in order to invoke it.
How does it get the path?

I succeeded to invoke the executable file to code "./node_modules//" as the path for local installation, but I am convinced that it is not a good idea as it must fail when installing globally.

Answer (score 0):

I found that __dirname works well in my case.